# How do I get the font styles on MacOS using Swift?

Tags: swift, menu

I am trying to make a Menu filled with font styles for a particular font.  In the code below I have one attempt that is commented out.  The code just below correctly prints the styles but I can't get the ForEach() to work.  GetFontStyles() seams to return an array of arrays and that internal array contains several fields including the font name, font style and some ID numbers.  Note the member[1] which is was used to pull the style.

```
struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel
    init(_ dm: DrawModel ) { self.dm = dm }
    
    var body: some View {
    var fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont )
//      ForEach(fontStyles, id: \.self) { curStyle in
//          Button( "xxx" ) {
//              print( "Style: \(curStyle)")
//      //      print("Type of Member: \(type(of: member)) - \(member[1])")
//          }
//      }
        Button( "xxx" ) {
            let fontStyles = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: dm.curFont)
            print("-\nFont: \(dm.curFont)")
            
            if let members = fontStyles {
                for member in members {
                    print("Style for: \(dm.curFont) - \(member[1])")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getFontStyles(for fontFamily: String) -> [String] {
     let fontManager = NSFontManager.shared

     guard let availableMembers = fontManager.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: fontFamily) else {
          return []
     }

     return availableMembers.compactMap { member in
         return member as? String
     }
}
```

**Edit 1**

My code is pretty close to yours except for some variable names and the addition of all the .onChange calls.  Using those to figure out which one is the correct location but none work.  Here You go:

```
struct AddFontItems: View {
var dm: DrawModel

init(_ dm: DrawModel ) { self.dm = dm }

var uniqueFontFamilies = NSFontManager.shared.availableFontFamilies.unique()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(uniqueFontFamilies, id: \.self) { curFont in
            Button( curFont) {
                dm.curFont = curFont
                print( "Set font to: " + dm.curFont )
            }
            .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
                //          fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
                print( "In onChange1.1" )
            }
        }
        .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
            //          fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
            print( "In onChange1.2" )
        }
        .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
            //          fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
            print( "In onChange1.3" )
        }
    }
}
}

struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel
    init(_ dm: DrawModel ) { self.dm = dm }

    @State private var fontStyles: [String] = []        // reusable for .onAppear

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(fontStyles, id: \.self) { curStyle in
                Button(curStyle) {
                    dm.curFontStyle = curStyle
                    print("Set Style:\t \(dm.curFontStyle)")
                }
                .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
                    fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
                    print( "In onChange2.1" )
                }
            }
            .onAppear { // TODO:  Called once on app launch.  Call on Font change
                fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
                print( "In onAppear" )
            }
            .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
                fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
                print( "In onChange2.2" )
            }
        }
        .onChange( of: dm.curFont ) { // <--- here
            //          fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
            print( "In onChange2.3" )
        }
    }
}

func getFontStyles(for font: String) -> [String] {
    var justStyles: [String] = []
    if let fontInfo = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: font ) {
         for curFontInfo in fontInfo {
              if curFontInfo.count > 1 {
                  justStyles.append(curFontInfo[1] as? String ?? "")
              }
         }
    }
    return justStyles
}
```

Comment: How about you try to use my code of `EDIT-2`, and see if this work for you.
 Note you cannot change `var dm: DrawModel` in your `AddFontItems`
 or `AddFontStyleItems` views, because it is immutable. Notice how I pass
 the `drawModel` from the parent view (ContentView) to the `AddFontStyleItems`.
 
 If you have to change the `var dm: DrawModel` in your `AddFontStyleItems` and in your `AddFontItems`
 you need to use `@Binding var dm: DrawModel`. **However** you do not need to
 do that, there is no need to change `dm` in those views. Use the approach I showed.

Comment: OK, I just read through that code and it appears that you're depending on using the inline version to 'get it now.' That must succeed as long as SwiftUI is clearing the content before a redraw is being called.  Give me 10m and I'll clean up everything and do what you suggested.

Comment: updated my answer (EDIT-3) with a way to change your `DrawModel`.

Comment: OK, I am using your approach how.  The menu is correct for the first font unfortunately not correct for the next font.  I am using Helvetica which has 6 styles some with the word Oblique in them and Arial which does not have any Oblique Styles instead they are old names such as Regular,  Bold and Italic.  I can't see those correct styles if use the application directly to change fonts BUT if I change my default font, re-compile and look at the styles menu it is then correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using a helper `struct FontModel` to
hold the font results and make it easier to use in the `ForEach` loop.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        AddFontStyleItems(DrawModel(curFont: "Helvetica"))
    }
}

// for testing
struct DrawModel {
    var curFont: String
}

struct FontModel: Identifiable {  // <--- here
    let id = UUID()
    var fontType: String
    var fontName: String
    var fontWeight: Int
    var fontTrait: Int
    
    init(_ arr: [Any]) {
        if arr.count < 5 {
            self.fontType = arr[0] as? String ?? ""
            self.fontName = arr[1] as? String ?? ""
            self.fontWeight = arr[2] as? Int ?? 0
            self.fontTrait = arr[3] as? Int ?? 0
        } else {
            self.fontType = ""
            self.fontName = ""
            self.fontWeight = 0
            self.fontTrait = 0
        }
    }
}

struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel
    @State private var fontStyles: [FontModel] = [] // <--- here
    
    init(_ dm: DrawModel) { self.dm = dm }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(fontStyles) { curStyle in  // <--- here
            Button(curStyle.fontName) {
                print("---> Style: \(curStyle)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont) // <--- here
        }
    }
    
    func getFontStyles(for fontFamily: String) -> [FontModel] {
        var results: [FontModel] = []
        if let members = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: fontFamily) {
            for member in members {
                results.append(FontModel(member))
            }
        }
        return results
    }

}
```

EDIT-1:

if just want an array of Strings

```
struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel
    @State private var fontStyles: [String] = [] // <--- here
    
    init(_ dm: DrawModel) { self.dm = dm }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(fontStyles, id: \.self) { curStyle in  // <--- here
            Button(curStyle) {
                print("---> Style: \(curStyle)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont) // <--- here
        }
        .onChange(of: dm.curFont) { // <--- here
            fontStyles = getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont)
        }
    }
    
    func getFontStyles(for fontFamily: String) -> [String] {
        var results: [String] = []
        if let members = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: fontFamily) {
            for member in members {
                if member.count > 1 {
                    results.append(member[1] as? String ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }

}
```

Or simply:

```
struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont), id: \.self) { curStyle in
                Button(curStyle) {
                    print("---> dm: \(dm)   Style: \(curStyle)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getFontStyles(for fontFamily: String) -> [String] {
        var results: [String] = []
        if let members = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: fontFamily) {
            for member in members {
                if member.count > 1 {
                    results.append(member[1] as? String ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }
    
}
```

EDIT-2:

Here is my full test code that shows, changing the `curFont` of the `drawModel` in the parent view,
changes the `AddFontStyleItems` view displaying the Font Styles. Tested on MacOS 14.4.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var drawModel = DrawModel(curFont: "Helvetica") // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change curFont") {
                drawModel.curFont = "Times"  // <--- here
            }.padding(20)
            Divider()
            Text(drawModel.curFont).foregroundStyle(.red)
            Divider()
            AddFontStyleItems(dm: drawModel)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct AddFontStyleItems: View {
    var dm: DrawModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont), id: \.self) { curStyle in
                Button(curStyle) {
                    print("---> dm: \(dm)   Style: \(curStyle)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getFontStyles(for fontFamily: String) -> [String] {
        var results: [String] = []
        if let members = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: fontFamily) {
            for member in members {
                if member.count > 1 {
                    results.append(member[1] as? String ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }
    
}

struct DrawModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var curFont: String
}
```

EDIT-3:

try this approach to `select` the `font` and the `style` for your `DrawModel`.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var drawModel = DrawModel(curFont: "", curStyle: "") // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(drawModel.curFont).foregroundStyle(.red)
            Text(drawModel.curStyle).foregroundStyle(.blue)
            Divider()
            AddFontItems(dm: $drawModel)  // <--- here $
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct AddFontItems: View {
    @Binding var dm: DrawModel // <--- here
    
    var uniqueFontFamilies = NSFontManager.shared.availableFontFamilies //.unique()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(uniqueFontFamilies, id: \.self) { curFont in
                    Button(curFont) {
                        dm.curFont = curFont
                        print("---> curFont: \(curFont)")
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(getFontStyles(for: dm.curFont), id: \.self) { curStyle in
                    Button(curStyle) {
                        dm.curStyle = curStyle
                        print("Set Style:\t \(curStyle)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getFontStyles(for font: String) -> [String] {
        var justStyles: [String] = []
        if let fontInfo = NSFontManager.shared.availableMembers(ofFontFamily: font ) {
            for curFontInfo in fontInfo {
                if curFontInfo.count > 1 {
                    justStyles.append(curFontInfo[1] as? String ?? "")
                }
            }
        }
        return justStyles
    }
}

struct DrawModel: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var curFont: String
    var curStyle: String
}
```

Comment: Ouch, sorry I didn't include my drawing model but that is pretty standard and you figured it out.  That seams to be a lot harder.  But I guess I could use your concept to return a single array of Just the styles.  IOW return an array of strings which is the list of styles.  Appending member[1] instead of the whole fontDetails.  I'll have to think about it since having the font details could be helpful.

Comment: updated my answer, for the case if you want just an array of Strings. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it by ticking the tick mark next to it, it turns green.

Comment: Hey, the string version seams to work (almost had that written myself changing variable names for readability :))... I saw that you added an .onAppear so I was trying to test that if it worked.  Seams that everything returns the same 6 basic styles.

Comment: Note, declaring a `var` inside the view body (your original code) is not a good idea.
The body can be refreshed whenever SwiftUI wants to do it.
 Hence, I use the more common approach with a `@State private var` and update it in `.onAppear{...}`.

Comment: I added a print statement to  the onAppear.  It ONLY gets called once on app launch.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use that function (getFontStyles)wherever you want to update some SwiftUI State. For example in a Button.

Comment: Update my answer to cater for refreshing the view when the `DrawModel` changes.

Comment: OK, I added onChange() to the original suggested location with a print statement and tested it didn't work.  I ended up adding to 4 locations to the buttons for Fonts and Styles and the for each statement for Fonts and Styles.  None of them triggered.  I only have one more idea which is to attach it to a VStack for each.

Comment: OK, all six locations did not work.  Maybe I have to register for notifications or some such thing.

Comment: updated my answer with the full test code I used. Let me know if my code does not work for you. I cannot test your code since you don't show it in your post. Note, I don't understand what you mean by `...adding 4 locations to the buttons ...`

Comment: OK I've included my latest code without the DrawingModel.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: OK, I've moved my current code to the end of my original message as Edit 1